# TypeError: require.exec is not a function error in js file

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am loading options with below code :

```
first_select.load(url,function(){
    first_select.change();
    first_select.closest("li").removeClass("loading");
});
```

Now i am getting this error :

> require.exec is not a function

anybody have any idea about this error ?